# Anyone knows if there is a lib for a Facebook image picker that works like a UIImagePickerController?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, uiimagepickercontroller

It sounds very common, something like a UIImagePicker that allows the user to browse all of his facebook albums and eventually pick an image and pass it to a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:
http://blog.grio.com/2012/03/picking-image-from-your-facebook-photos-in-ios.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at customizing the image picker supplised in **Three20**. This is a library that Facebook developers shared with all of their material. [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20)

> Photo Viewer: TTPhotoViewController emulates Apple's Photos app with all of its flick n' pinch delight. You can supply your own "photo sources", which works similiarly to the data sources used by UITableView. Unlike Apple's Photos app, it isn't limited to photos stored locally. Your photos can be loaded from the network, and long lists of photos can be loaded incrementally.

Instead of having it view the photo, you could modify the code to pass the image to a delegate instead.

Comment: Thanks, i know about Three20, i'm afraid it's not what i need,  guess i'll write it and share here later, it just seem very basic functionally for any image app out there to allow the user to choose an image from facebook